# Extend repository in TYPO3 9.5 LTS / Extbase

Tags: typo3, extends, extbase, php-7.2

I'm trying to extend this [IndexRepository](https://github.com/lochmueller/calendarize/blob/master/Classes/Domain/Repository/IndexRepository.php) to add my own method for a special search.

In the controller I inject my own IndexRepository with:

```
use Webian\Iancalendar\Domain\Repository\IndexRepository;

/**
 * Inject index repository.
 *
 * @param IndexRepository $indexRepository
 */
public function injectIndexRepository(IndexRepository $indexRepository)
{
    $this->indexRepository = $indexRepository;
}
```

What I did is working but I get this warning:

```
PHP Warning
Core: Error handler (BE): PHP Warning: Declaration of Webian\Iancalendar\Controller\
BackendController::injectIndexRepository(Webian\Iancalendar\Domain\Repository\IndexRepository $indexRepository)
should be compatible with HDNET\Calendarize\Controller\
AbstractController::injectIndexRepository(HDNET\Calendarize\Domain\Repository\IndexRepository $indexRepository)
in /typo3conf/ext/iancalendar/Classes/Controller/BackendController.php line 42
```

That's because I'm using my own `Webian\Iancalendar\Domain\Repository\IndexRepository` that extends `HDNET\Calendarize\Domain\Repository\IndexRepository`. If I use the original one the warning doesn't appear but obviously my own method is not called.

How can I avoid that warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either not extend `HDNET\Calendarize\Controller\AbstractController` but the default `AbstractController` of Extbase, then you will need to implement all required logic yourself.

Or you just use a different name for your injection method:

```php
use HDNET\Calendarize\Controller\AbstractController;
use MyNamespace\MyExtension\Domain\Repository\IndexRepository;

class MyController extends AbstractController
{

...

    /**
    * The index repository.
    *
    * @var IndexRepository
    */
    protected $myIndexRepository;

    /**
    * Inject index repository.
    *
    * @param IndexRepository $myIndexRepository
    */
    public function injectMyIndexRepository(IndexRepository $myIndexRepository)
    {
        $this->myIndexRepository = $myIndexRepository;
    }

...

class IndexRepository extends \HDNET\Calendarize\Domain\Repository\IndexRepository
{

...

    // My method that extends \HDNET\Calendarize\Domain\Repository\IndexRepository functionalities
    public function findByStartDate(DateTime $startDate = null, DateTime $endDate = null)
    {

...
```

The method name does not really matter, only that it starts with `inject` and has a type hint indicating the dependency to inject.

Comment: I have adopted your second option and it works, thanks! But, just to better understand Extbase, I also tried your first option, that is to directly extend the default AbstractController of Extbase, and it didn't work for me. Maybe I did something wrong but, if I understood correctly, if I don't extend HDNET\Calendarize\Controller\AbstractController then I should recreate all its logic and the logic of what it extends, am I wrong?

Comment: Correct, I've adjusted my answer accordingly.